# Supporting images/diagrams in exported org-mode presentations

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I'm currently preparing a presentation which I've outlined in `org-mode` and I'm having difficulty in including diagrams in the exported HTML. I'm currently using [`org-reveal`](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal) but I'm happy to use another HTML presentation exporter if needed. `org-reveal` does offer the option to include HTML directly in the presentation but that seems a little hacky. Surely there is a better way to specify that an image should be in-line in the final exported output?

Comment: Hmmm it seems the solution is to drop the link name :-/

Comment: Image export using org-reveal works for me. I simply use `[[file:./path/to/img/img.png]]`

Comment: Does this help? [The Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Images-in-ODT-export)

Comment: @stsquad yeah, that's not terribly intuitive, but if a link has a description org won't turn it into an image. If it solved your problem write it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images can be exported as Inline in two styles: with hyperlink or without hyperlink.

**Inline With Hyperlink**

```
[[file:./image.png][file:./image_thumbnail.png]]
```

Note that it is mandatory to put a prefix like `file:` or `http:` in the *Description* portion (`[file:./image_thumbnail.png]`) of the above image link; otherwise `ox-html` will export that as a text hyperlink pointing to the image.png.

You can use simply reuse image.png instead of image_thumbnail.png.

*Below examples will result in inline image hyperlinks pointing to `./image.png`:*

> ```
> [[file:./image.png][file:./image.png]]
> [[./image.png][file:./image.png]]
> [[file:./image.png][file:./other-image.png]]
> ```

**Inline Without Hyperlink**

```
[[file:./image.png]]
```

*Below examples will result in inline images without hyperlinks:*

> ```
> [[file:./image.png]]
> [[./image.png]]
> ```

---

**Text hyperlink to image**

```
[[file:./image.png][Any text that doesn't begin with file:]]
```

*Below examples will result in text hyperlinks pointing to `./image.png`:*

> ```
> [[file:./image.png][Description]]
> [[file:./image.png][./image.png]]
> [[./image.png][./image.png]]
> ```

Comment: To display several images on the same slide, add formatting options before each picture:
`#+ATTR_HTML: :style float:left; margin:20px ; width: 250px;`

Answer (score 1):

The details are in the [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-HTML-export.html) but I missed it. Basically you need to ensure you don't add a title. So:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :alt Architectural overview :style border:none;
[[file:diagrams/RISU_Architecture_Overview.svg]]
```